Naming convention for TypeScript generic → specific → union
export type TypeaheadTransaction<Action> = Transaction & {
  getMeta(key: PluginKey<TypeaheadState>): Action;
};

export type AcceptOneWord = TypeaheadTransaction<{
  type: 'ACCEPT_ONE_WORD';
}>;

export type ResetState = TypeaheadTransaction<{
  type: 'RESET_STATE';
}>;

export type TypeaheadTransaction = AcceptOneWord | ResetState;

My issue is that my generic and my union type would have the identical name, and I'm not aware of any naming convention for a generic as opposed to a union of it's generated specific types..
Is this a bad idea? I've done a fair amount of digging through Stack Overflow, reddit, Google, ChatGPT, etc., but can't find anyone using this type of a pattern for creating type definitions.

I think I'm just going with GenericTypeaheadTransaction, I don't see anyone prefixing or suffixing with G or T or anything, and I think the name is fitting

Some ideas: BaseTypeaheadTransaction<Action>, TypeaheadTransactionOf<Action>
